# Импорты данных в таблицу через консоль

Tags: sql, консоль

Скажите, как можно через консоль импортировать в базу данных mySql некоторые данные в определенную таблицу, т.е. не всю базу, а выборочные данные? Что-то аналогичное SQL-запросу `` INSERT INTO `название таблицы` (...) VALUES... ``

Comment: Какие данные? откуда, в каком формате?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось крайне просто, тот же самый запрос, что используюется в phpMyAdmin, только без ковычек указывается название таблицы:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO название_таблицы (`имя поля`, `имя поля`, `имя поля`,) VALUES (‘значение’, ’значение’, ‘значение’);
```

Comment: *только без ковычек указывается название таблицы* Связь-то какая?

Comment: да, можно и с кавычками) ошибся. Получается, тот же самый sql-запрос, только через терминал.

Comment: Вот какая серверу разница, откуда к нему попал запрос? текст - всегда один и тот же. Если нет - то это "медвежья услуга" клиента, который посчитал себя слишком умным...